# Copy array to a different class's array variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am attempting to copy an array in my ViewController to a Data storage class.  None of the array copy methods I have found are actually working.  Currently I have..

```
   //XML parser is returning an array of parsed objects
    NSMutableArray *randomtesting = [parser listArray];
    customerList.list =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:randomtesting copyItems:YES];

    NSLog(@"First node randomtesting: %@",[randomtesting objectAtIndex:0]);
    NSLog(@"First node customerList: %@",[customerList.list objectAtIndex:0]);
```

The first NSLog prints out the value correctly.  The second prints out a Null.  I have also tried

```
customerList.list =randomtesting;
```

and

```
customerList.list = [paser listArray];
```

The .h of my Viewcontroller for this class is as follows

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@class CustomerListData;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>{

    CustomerListData *customerList;

}


@property (nonatomic, retain) CustomerListData *customerList;
```

The class's .h of the array variable is

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface CustomerListData : NSObject{

   NSMutableArray *list;
 }


 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *list;

 @end
```

the .m is just

```
@synthesize list;
```

I believe all of my variable declarations are correct, I'm just not copying it correctly.  But I none of the methods seem to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you initializing your ViewController's `customerList` property anywhere i.e. doing something like this:

```
self.customerList = [[[CustomerListData alloc] init] autorelease];
```

If not, then this property will be `nil` and all your attempts at accessing the customerList.list child property will fail silently because you are sending an Objective-C message to `nil`.